# Not enough permissions to access: GET /v2/ugcPosts - LinkedIn API for fetching single share photo_mention details by Share Id from personal profile

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch linkedin share photo_mention details using GET /v2/ugcPosts - LinkedIn API. I'm using it for fetch single photo_mention details by Share Id. 3-legged oauth2 token im using is valid and having access to below permissions:

`r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, r_member_social, r_organization_social, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social`

For photo mention posts shared from organization page im able to fetch ugcpost details using above api call, but for photo mention posts shared from personal page I'm getting below error:

```
{
"message": "com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:403]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: Not enough permissions to access urn:li:share:xxxxxx",
"status": 403
}
```

Please guide me in this to solve this error.

[Postman screenshot of failed api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb8il.png)

[LinkedIn Developer API used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwXbU.png)

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn Support seems to be terminated - facing the same issue when trying to access the 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/' endpoint...

Update: Well, just found out that the permission 'r_member_social' in this case is RESTRICTED. So I guess you just can retrieve share infos for posts on ORGA pages, not private profiles... -> Restricted Retrieve posts, comments, and likes on behalf of an authenticated member. This is a private permission. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http

Comment: please edit your own post instead of using comments - otherwise it will be downvoted and/or closed